# Android studio enable to move app to SD card

Tags: android

I have some issues to moving my application to the SD card storage,
I changed in the `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
android.installLocation="auto"
```

However I still have an error when I try to move the app to the SD card       "not enough storage space" though I have 20 GB available on my SD card.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    package="com.example.mouad.kanjiapp"

    android:installLocation="auto"

    android:versionCode="2" android:versionName="1.2">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Error when trying to move the app to the SD card:

> [image: Error when trying to move the app to the SD card]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's also `android:installLocation="preferExternal"`, which would prefer install to SD.

also see the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location), for apps which should not be installed to external storage.

also, when the SD card being mounted via USB cable - you'll get that error.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I changed to loke like this android:installLocation="preferExternal" and work fine for me.                                             I will check the official documentation to see the preferences.

Answer (score 1):

Although accepted as an answer this is wrong. You avoided the problem by changing the manisfest yet again. If you want "auto" to work you have to create a *signed* build and install this version manually to the emulator. It will not show you this weird and wrong error message. Source:
[SD Card Transfer (not enough storage space)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47274126/sd-card-transfer-not-enough-storage-space)